# Curl Output not showing

Tags: php, curl, output

Below is my code but it's not showing output. Now I temporarily shown yahoo.com as the `curl` output but my actual output url is different. Can anyone tell me what's the problem in the code?

```
<?php
    $myurl = "www.yahoo.com";
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $myurl);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $result= curl_exec ($ch); //execute and get the results
    echo $result; //display the reuslt
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This:

```
//Add $ch = curl_init();
$ch = curl_init();

$myurl = "www.yahoo.com";
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $myurl);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result= curl_exec ($ch); //execute and get the results
echo $result; //display the reuslt
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your are not initializing the curl use this:

```
 <?php

 $myurl = "www.yahoo.com";
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $myurl);
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 $result= curl_exec ($ch); //execute and get the results
 echo $result; //display the reuslt
 curl_close($ch);
 ?>
```